# Using reflection to cast an object in java for android

Tags: java, android, reflection

How can i reduce this to a couple of lines using reflection in java for android?

(**_properties** is a ContentValues object and **value** is an object)

```
    if (value instanceof String)
    {
        this._properties.put(   key,    value.toString());
    } else if (value instanceof Long) {
        this._properties.put(   key,    Long.valueOf(value.toString()));
    } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
        this._properties.put(   key,    Integer.valueOf(value.toString()));
    } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
        this._properties.put(   key,    Boolean.valueOf(value.toString()));
    } else if (value instanceof Byte) {
        this._properties.put(   key, Byte.valueOf(value.toString()));
    } else ...
```

Comment: I am not Android developer so I'm sorry for my ignorance, but why are you even checking type of `value`? Is there a problem with `this._properties.put(key, value);`?

Comment: @Pshemo `ContentValues` does not have a generic `put object` method, only typed methods for a certain types (because of internal serialisation / parceling): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html When using these it would be better to cast instead of converting to a String but this would reduce the code needed only slightly (e.g `this._properties.put(key,(Byte)value)`).

Comment: `this._properties.put(key,(Byte)value))` is the same to `this._properties.put(key,Byte.valueOf(value.toString()))` , right?

Comment: @his Thanks for clarification, it makes more sense now. Main problem is that reference OP is using is `Object` type like `Object value = giveMeYourMoney()` and it should be used with correct `put` method because there is no general `put(String, Object)` which would get rid of ambiguity.

Comment: @Xabier No, even if the result _in this case_ is the same but the procedure is not. With `toString / valueOf` the value is converted to a String and then converted back to the original value. Because of the return type of `valueOf` the compiler knows which `put` method to use, but the converting itself does nothing effectively. With casting you tell the compiler directly which method to use. The keyword is "early binding".

Answer (score 2):

No reflection needed:

```
 _properties.put(key, value.toString());
```

Unfortunately `ContentValues` does not have `put(String, Object)` even though internally the values are stored in `HashMap<String, Object>`.

Why storing values as `String` works is that all `ContentValues` `getAsFoo()` accessors support converting to `Foo` from `String`.

Comment: So you mean i could use value.toString() to store the value and still use instanceOf later on..? `(_properties instanceOf [whatever_type_here])`

Comment: The values will be stored as `String`s so the type information is lost if you use the generic `get() : Object` to access. But the `getAs...()` accessors will attempt to convert `String`s to the requested type before giving up.

Comment: While this is a viable method it is different to the original code as you lose the type. For types that can't be serialized to a String without loss the value may be slightly different after deserialization (`Float`, `Double`). In most cases these problems will be insignificant - you don't handle arbitrary data so you know the types associated with certain keys, and I guess as of now there are not much applications out there that need full precision (except for beginner code that compares floating point values with `==` ). On the other hand you write the original code (with casting) just once.